# My SQL Query was running slow intermittently. I have run the below mentioned query to check for I/O issue

Tags: sql-server

from the query I found that 50% of wait time is because of PAGEIOLATCH_EX. Is this 50% is enough to cause the slowness issue..

```
Wait_Type   Wait_Time_Seconds   Waiting_Tasks_Count Percentage_WaitTime
PAGEIOLATCH_EX  409641.298000   107452979   50.198968970559780
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2019

Comment: Looking at a single wait type in isolation can often lead you in the wrong direction. It's like focusing on a single hair while unaware of whether it's attached to a mouse or a tiger. You probably need to spend some time in Resource Monitor to see which database files/logs are hot, whether they're read- or write-heavy, then examine the disk subsystems looking for bottlenecks and misconfigurations. Even so it may be caused by other things such as SQL Server being memory starved having to perform regular disk I/O because it cannot cache enough page data in memory.

Comment: this is something I can check at my end..  I do not have access to the server to check resource monitoring..

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-wait-type-pageiolatch-sh/

This wait type accumulates while SQL Server is waiting for a page to be retrieved from disk and loaded into memory. The page collected will be used for a shared purpose (read operation). If this value is high it is likely disk or memory available are not keeping up with the workload

Comment: yes.. This is know.. But what does high actually means here... Is there some kind of threshold.. like above 20% is high..?

Comment: PAGEIOLATCH_EX not PAGEIOLATCH_SH